# Using gspread, trying to color many strings

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, gspread

In google sheets, I am trying to find many strings and highlight them, so say, "Find", "Find2", "Find3", "Find4". Please see below.

```
cell_list = worksheet.findall("find", "find2", "find3", "find4")
```

Answer (score 1):

In that case, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
cell_list = worksheet.findall("find", "find2", "find3", "find4")
```

#### To:

```
regex = re.compile("find|find2|find3|Find4")
cell_list = worksheet.findall(regex)
```

and

```
regex = re.compile("find(\d+)?", re.IGNORECASE)
cell_list = worksheet.findall(regex)
```

In this modification, the regex is used for `findall`.

#### Reference:

[gspread API Reference - findall](https://docs.gspread.org/en/latest/api.html?highlight=findall#gspread.worksheet.Worksheet.findall)

Comment: That makes alot more sense, Taniake. That was helpful!